# Why I'm getting burning marks of the sun on render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, shaders

I'm getting this burning marks in the sky and i don't why and how to get rid of it.
I have no composition, just sky texture Nishita. Previous project i had also some issues, didn't use sky texture, it was a HDRI, and same problem on the Final Render.
I'm using 2.90 version

Here is a image:

[image]

How can i fix it?

Here is the blend file:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: It is hard to understand what it is you are showing in the images. Consider sharing your project with the images packed into it so that others can inspect it and help you.

Comment: Thank you, i already put the blend file

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with the supplied file. I wonder if that is an issue caused by the drivers on the GPU, what kind of system are you working on?

Comment: I'm using RTX 2060 6gb, CPU AMD Ryzen 2700X, 16Gb Ram

Comment: Try updating (or downgrading) the drivers for the GPU.

Comment: It Worked! I updated the drivers for the GPU. Thank you